# phantomjs: how to run script with object.assign function?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I try to run phantomjs script for website that inculde js with Object.assign function and get an error:

`TypeError:: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Object.assign')`.

As i understand, phantomjs doesn't use ES-2015. So i need to use polyfill like [this](https://github.com/chuckplantain/phantomjs-polyfill-object-assign). I tried to make it work with injectJs, includeJs or even require with absolute url, but it still doesn't work.

How to import this js and run script?

Comment: You can't run phantomjs in your Browser. This isn't a client library.

Comment: You can use [MDN's polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill), just copy paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the webpage running Object.assign in a child frame. If so, you have to use a polyfill in that frame. You can use the following PhantomJS expression to print frame names on the page:

```
console.log('Current frames: ' + JSON.stringify(page.childFramesName()));
```

If so, you could inject polyfill in every frame:

```
page.injectJs('polyfills.js');

page.childFramesName().forEach(function(childFrameName) {
    page.switchToFrame(childFrameName);

    page.injectJs('polyfills.js');

    page.switchToMainFrame();
});
```